# getting username and hostname from a database in ssh program in python

Tags: python, mysql, networking

```
import paramiko 
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.connect(hostname=’hostname’,username=’mokgadi’,password=’mypassword’)
```

I want to get hostname and username from a mysql database in python.
So please anyone can answer it very early

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is about? You want your code snippet to work within your environment? Or you want to extract `username` and `password` using this code? Or what are you trying to achieve? Please provide some more context.

Comment: Actually I want to do something like this:  I have a drop down list in a gui, where an ip value is selected and clicking a button, which is below the drop down list, will automatically fill up the username and password from a database according to the ip value in a ssh program. So if u need the whole code to answer I can post it...but if u can give me a general code for this, then I will be greatfull.             I did the drop down list, but clicking the button it cant connect to remote computer

Answer (score 1):

Use a mysql client, as described [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).
After that your code would be something like:

```
import paramiko
import _mysql
import sys

con = None
try:
    con = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'testpassword', 'testdb')

    mytable = 'users' #your tablename
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.execute("SELECT user, password from {0}".format(mytable)) # or whatever fields you want/need
    row = cur.fetchone()
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='hostname', username=row[0], password=row[1])
except _mysql.Error as e:
    print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually I used mysql.connector and wrote the program. This program also works by importing paramiko.  Thank you